# How to determine $\varphi$ in spherical coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

Assume that I would like to integrate some continuous a.e. function $f(x,y,z)$ over the following set: $ a^2_1 \le x^2 + y^2 +z^2 \le  a^2_2$, and $z\ge c^2(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$. So, in a case I would like to convert to spherical coordinates, then clearly $a_1^2 \le x^2 + y^2 \le a_2^2$, hence $a_1 \le r \le a_2$, and because the projection on the $x\times y$ plane is two circles of radius $a_1$ and $a_2$, then $\theta \in [0, 2\pi]$. But how to determine $\varphi$ in this case?

Comment: $z=\rho \cos(\phi),r:=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\rho \sin(\phi)$, so $z=c^2(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$ is the same as $\cot(\phi)=c^2$. (This is under the spherical coordinate convention $x=\rho \sin(\phi) \cos(\theta),y=\rho \sin(\phi) \sin(\theta),z=\rho \cos(\theta),\theta \in [0,2\pi],\phi \in [0,\pi]$.)

Comment: $\cot(\phi) \geq 1 \Leftrightarrow \phi \leq \operatorname{arccot}(1)=\pi/4$, since $\cot$ is decreasing on $[0,\pi]$.

Comment: Thank you. I guess that there is no any other "intutive" way to find, right? Anyway, If you  post it as an answer - I'll except it.

Comment: I mean, there is a way to do it based on drawing triangles, but it is just a geometric picture which I just described algebraically above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inequality $z \geq c^2(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$ is equivalent to $\cot(\varphi) \geq 1$. Since $\cot$ is decreasing this is equivalent to $\operatorname{arccot}(\varphi) \leq \pi/4$.